# Is threading required?

Tags: php, android, json

I have a web hosting server that will send and receive data to multiple android phones via json.

For example if 5 phones have to send and receive data via json to the server and the server have to send and receive the data simultaneously, do I have to write any threading in my php script to handle multiple json request from the clients?

[image]

Comment: What is your server configuration ? Apache / nginx ? How do you use the server ? Any framework, to make some REST calls ? Do you have any time-constraints... ?

Comment: if you are running your app on a real-life webserver (apache, nginx, etc)  : No, that part will be handled by the webserver and/or the php-fpm pool and it will spawn as many pocess as it needs.

Comment: It's my first time purchasing web hosting from a web hosting service company(hostgator) and my knowledge on webserver is at best shallow. that's why I am asking.

Comment: of course you don't have to do threadings. web servers always handle this kind situations. there's only one thing you will have to take care of, that is if one request may affect other ones, like there're dependencies between them. you'll have to use a queue(rabbit mq) to make the requests handled in a certain sequence.

Comment: then don't worry about that. Apache's php-mod or php-fpm will spawn some php processes (number depends on configuration) to serve user's requests. threading in your script would help to speedup some tasks that can be done simultaneously in your scripts, but is not relevant for request-handling.

Comment: thank you for information all